# ASP.NET C# - How to show message that session has expired?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have an ASP.NET C# in Web Forms. I made it redirect to the login page when the session times out. Here is my code in the master page:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", Convert.ToString(Session.Timeout * 60) + "; URL=");
if (HttpContext.Current.Session["authenticated"] == null)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/");
}
```

How can I make a notification message appear in the sign in page, when it was redirected there because of a session timeout? For example, the message would be "Your session has expired".

Comment: Do you know how to pass information via query string?

Comment: See the comment of @mason. do a search on that. It's as good as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I changed the code to:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", Convert.ToString(Session.Timeout * 60) + "; URL=?error=sessionexpired");
if (HttpContext.Current.Session["authenticated"] == null)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/?error=invalidsession");
}
```

Then, in my sign in page:

```
if (Request["error"]  == "sessionexpired") {
    msg = "Your session has expired";
}
else if (Request["error"] == "invalidsession")
{
    msg = "Please sign in to continue";
}
```